# WPF Datagrid Combobox SelectedItem not Binding to Powershell Object correctly

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, binding, datagrid

I am having a bit of trouble correctly binding my Datagrid ComboBox selected item to my PowerShell object. I am using a two way binding for the ComboBox with an 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged' parameter. The source objects correctly get added as items to the ComboBoxes and the source object will update as a selection is changed. However When I save the object or else launch for the first time, the selected items do not get bound. Instead all ComboBoxes are generated as having no selected value.

XAML:

```
          <DataGrid Name="CustomDescription_Fields_DG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="626" Margin="185,113,0,87" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFEFEFF2" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Field}" Header="Applied Fields" Width="395"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Position" Visibility="Visible" Width="60">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Position, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCount}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource
                               {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

WPF application launched:

You can see that when the application is launched that the ComboBox items are correctly bound to the 'ItemCount' field of the ItemsSource object. What should happen (or at least what I'm trying to achieve) is that the selected item should be the item that is defined within the 'Position' field of the ItemsSource object.

This is a breakdown of what is happening:

[image]

I'm not to sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated.

[Object being added as Itemssource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtcIR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define DisplayMemberPath and SelectedItem binding.  If you have provided some more code I could have shown you exactly what it should look like.  Here is an example from some of my code...

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" DisplayMemberPath="Symbol" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedToUnit}" />
```

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for replying. Could you please shed some light on what exactly the 'DisplayMemberPath' is set to? Above I have edited my original post with some PS code outlining how the object is applied to the Datagrid. If you need any more code just let me know. Im desperate to work this out!

Comment: In my example Symbol is a name of a column in the DataTable which is in my case the ItemsSource.  Everything depends on the organization of the ItemsSource for the combobox.  I suspect in your case this is simply a list of integers and so you can leave this out.

Comment: Yes, my itemsource is a column containing integers 1-10. Then i have a second column containing a single integer that i would like to be the selected value of the combobox. The binding works in the sence that if i select one of the integers from the combobox my itemsource object is updated correctly, but once the datagrid is refreshed the combobox goes back to displaying no selected item...

Comment: The problem with the combobox in the datagrid is that you have two ItemsSource, one for the table and one for the combobox.  I suspect you are confusing the two.  The SelectedItem is a binding to a column in the ItemsSource for the datagrid.  I think that is the problem.  But you have now shown use the organization of either ItemsSource so I cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

Here I created a more complete example using a template datagrid column.

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Declared">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox  SelectedValue="{Binding DummyColumn}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Number" 
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DummyCollection, Source={x:Reference dummyElement}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I need a reference to a dummy element to get data context right...

```
    <FrameworkElement x:Name="dummyElement" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

In the code behind here is my data class and collection

```
    public class DummyClass
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

...

```
        DummyClassCollection = new ObservableCollection<DummyClass>();

        DummyClassCollection.Add(new DummyClass() { Name = "Item1", Number = 0 });
        DummyClassCollection.Add(new DummyClass() { Name = "Item2", Number = 1 });
        DummyClassCollection.Add(new DummyClass() { Name = "Item3", Number = 2 });
```

The data table which to which the datagrid is bound...

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("DummyColumn", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Bool", typeof(bool));
        table.Rows.Add(1,true);
        table.Rows.Add(2,false);
```

So comparing this example against yours, it seems perhaps that the problem is SelectedValue versus SelectedItem.

Again is the very hard to sort out your problem without knowing more about the structure of your bound data.