# How to get selected ComboBox-entry in DataGrid? (PowerShell WPF)

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

I'm trying to make a ComboBox inside of a DataGrid. I achieved to populate the ComboBox with a `PSCustomObject`. But I don't know how I get the selected Item from the Combobox, after selecting a row... (and the script's creating a new row called "DropDown", which I don't want)

I think it has something to do with the Bindings in the XAML, but I can't figure it out.

I already searched the Internet and found nothing helpful. For example, I found these posts from the same guy:

- [WPF Datagrid Combobox SelectedItem not Binding to Powershell Object correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093526/wpf-datagrid-combobox-selecteditem-not-binding-to-powershell-object-correctly)
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a80766bf-89aa-458c-8003-d154c74f6e3f/wpf-datagrid-combobox-selecteditem-not-binding-to-powershell-object-correctly?forum=ITCG

But he doesn't post any code, so I can't check how he solved it in his script.

---

The Script is just a small example to test the combobox.

You can find the script here: https://pastebin.com/75nsJFzL

My goal is to get the values from the whole row, plus the selected entry in the combobox.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Actually I didn't tried anything yet. I changed the script now a little bit ([Link](https://pastebin.com/75nsJFzL)) --> I moved the Columns in the XML.

But I didn't tried anything yet, to get the selcted item from the combobox. I saw on the Internet, that I can use the "SelectedItem"-Property, but I still don't know how I can get the Value from the Binding in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem an I solved it this way:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rezept">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyRecipe.Name}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.RecipeList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding MyRecipe}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

`MyRecipe` is in the DataContext of this DataGrid, but `RecipeList` is only in the DataContext of the ancestor of the DataGrid. In the end of the `CellEditingTemplate` is the term `SelectedValue="{Binding MyRecipe}"` witch gives the result of the combobox back. In this case it is saved in `MyRecipe`.
I hope this helps You.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.

I never worked with XML-Bindings before, and I can't get those bindings with `{ Binding Path=DataContext.Something}` to work. I think I'm missing some code, but don't really know what.

Is it possible to post your code, so I can look up how you solved it in the code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same issue..I think I might be trying to get the selected row the wrong way or something